# Can we make scrollable bottom tabbed page in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, scrollable, tabbedpage, bottomtabs

I am having four tabs on the bottom, the problem is, the last tab title is not completely visible, I am thinking by setting tab mode to scrollable it would set, Even after I set the `tabmode` to scrollable the problem exists.

can someone help me to achieve this, please.
[image]

[image]

Here is my xaml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="LightGray"
             android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="White"
             android:TabbedPage.IsSmoothScrollEnabled="True"         
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.DashBoardTabbedPage" BarBackgroundColor="#00abbf">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
</TabbedPage>
```

xaml.cs constructor

```
var  _dashboardview = new DashBoard();
            _dashboardview.Title = "1";
            _dashboardview.IconImageSource = "refresh";
            this.Children.Add(_dashboardview); //Added other 3 tabs in this way
            On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
```

Comment: Why are you doing the tabs in native android instead of a shared xaml view?

Comment: Please clarify because your question is about Xamarin.Forms (uses xaml) while your code is Xamarin.Android (Native, uses xml) it is completely different. So Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: I have defined tabbedpage in shared itself @o_w , The code is for reference about how I defined the tabMode.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Cfun, I am using xaml. I will update my xaml code.

Comment: I have updated my code @o_w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested you can change your application base page to the newer [Shell type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs), then use a combination of nesting `Tabbar` and `Tab` to define bottom and upper tabs. Although the default behavior is that beyond 5 bottom tabs the remaining ones will be hidden in a grouped list accessed thru a 3 dots "More" menu on the right edge.

[image]

But, if you prefer having scrollable tabs, I recommend using either one of the below package as it is not built-in inside Xamarin.Forms:

- [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/) with `TabView` gives great control and customization options for your tabs, including a built-in scrolling, the documentation will soon be available the same for the first stable release (planned for this week but already available in pre-releases), but meantime you can take a look at [TabView](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-communitytoolkit/blob/master/docs/views/tabview.md). Please note that this packages comes with plenty of diverse and helpful features not only for Tabs.

[image]

- Another nice package that you can take a look at is [Sharpnado.Tabs](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs) with `TabType.Scrollable`.

Comment: Thank you @cfun, I will try this.